# Python: How can Kernel PCA be performed via SVD?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, pca

Since standard PCA can be performed via either eigenvalue decomposition (`numpy.linalg.eig`) or Singular Value Decomposition (`numpy.linalg.svd`) how can I perform numpy - based PCA via SVD? Say I have the kernel matrix K, via eigenvalue decomposition:

```
# Technically untested, modded from the kernel-PCA package source
# Sometimes eigenvalues are negative for some reason
eVals, eVecs = numpy.linalg.eig(K)
normed = np.array(sorted([
    ...:     [val, vec/val] for val, vec in itertools.starmap(lambda e1, e2: (np.sqrt(e1),e1) , zip(eVals, eVecs.T))
    ...: ], key=lambda k:k[0],reverse=True))
```

What the SVD equivalent be? For standard PCA we SVD the input matrix **X** and eigen decompose the Covariance [image: Covariance] and Gram [image] matrices to get equivalents to **U, S, V**.